# Netbeans 8 and 7.4 Problems on CentOS 6.5

Tags: netbeans-7, centos6

I am new to Linux and my boss ordered me to install Netbeans software to one of CentOS 6.5 desktop.
I have downloaded and install Netbeans 7.4 along with Java jdk package. Installation was fine but when I try to execute the Netbeans icon, nothing happens.
I even go the the netbeans installation directory Netbeans 7.4/bin/ netbean and try to execute in terminal but nothing happens. It does not give any error,just not start. Please help. I have tried both the Netbeans version 7.4 and 8,but same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well I have downloaded the 32 bit version of NETBEANs and JDK package, but my OS is 64 bit...silly :) now I have installed correct version of JDK and Netbeans and its working.